# Applications of lattice reduction to mathematical results

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

This is a reference request question, if this is not the correct forum please point me to somewhere that is more appropriate for this question.

Have there been any uses of lattice reductions (most famously the [LLL](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) algorithm) in proving mathematical theorems, or to compute counterexamples? Three examples that I know of are:

- [disproof](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/301661264.pdf) of Mertens conjecture
- finding [rational points](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0005139.pdf) near curves by Elkies.
- computing Hilbert's class polynomial by using the fact that the $j$-invariant is an algebraic number, so one can compute pairs of isogenous elliptic curves, compute their $j$-invariant over complex numbers, compute an approximation to Hilbert's class polynomial, then round it. I can't find the reference to this but IIRC it is implemented in Sage.

An excellent survey by Simon ([Selected Applications of LLL in Number Theory](https://simond.users.lmno.cnrs.fr/maths/lll25_Simon.pdf)) gives the following applications:

- One can compute the Hermite Normal Form (HNF) and the Smith Normal
  Form (SNF) of a matrix
- LLL helps find integer / rational linear relations between real numbers. For example, reducing the matrix spanned by $(\arctan(1), 0, 0), (\arctan\left(\frac{1}{5}\right), 1, 0), (\arctan\left(\frac{1}{239}\right), 0, 1)$ yields a linear combination that sums to $0$, yielding Machin's formula. It has been used to find formulas for $\zeta(7)$ and generalised (and later proven) to $\zeta(4k + 3)$.
- Minkowski's theorem on lattices can be used to prove the sum of four squares theorem, and the proof can be turned into a constructive algorithm using lattice reductions.
- Lattice reduction can compute a reduced defining polynomial for a number field. For example, to compute the polynomial for $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$, the standard proof yields a polynomial with coefficients $\sim 2^{22}$, while applying lattice reduction gives $x^{16} - 7x^{12} + 48x^8 - 7x^4 + 1$. This speeds up computation with algebraic numbers.
- Lattice reduction is used in computing class groups, or more specifically to reduce the relations found between ideal classes to accelerate computation.
- Following the application by Elkies above, it has been extended and applied to the abc conjecture and the Szpiro conjecture, providing further numerical evidence.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) lists some applications and points out the reference $[7]$: " D. Simon (2007). "Selected applications of LLL in number theory" (PDF). LLL+25 Conference. Caen, France.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh, I did *not* expect the wikipedia page to contain resources :) I will edit some of them into my post.